# Sync Dropbox to lowercase folder

Tags: linux, sync, dropbox, user-folders

I am in the process of lowercasing my linux system, but I found a hurdle: Dropbox partout does not want to reside in a lowercased folder.

Changing the folder via GUI, it always wants to go into a subfolder that is named "Dropbox" and accepts nothing else. Editing the `~/.dropbox/info.json` doesn't seem to do *anything*.

Is there a way to force it to lowercase without resorting to symlinks or the like?